# Maximum number of databases in arangodb

Tags: arangodb

I am a new user of Arango DB and I am currently evaluating it for my project.
Can someone please tell me, what the maximum number of databases you can create in Arango DB is?

Thanks.

Comment: The theoretical limit based on the [database name constraints](https://docs.arangodb.com/NamingConventions/DatabaseNames.html) is somewhere around `4e+115` if I didn't screw up the calculation entirely (well, probably I did, but if it's `6.8e+110`, you would still not get into trouble cause of the naming restrictions :D)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there are virtually no limits to the number of databases in ArangoDB. 
The only thing you have to keep in mind, are the resources that are needed for databases and their collections.

Some of those resources, for each Database / Collection, are:

- Files on disk: space and file descriptors needed.
- Memory: each Database / Collection will take up space on the disk (and also in memory when loaded.)

For a collection, the number of file descriptors needed at any time is dependent of the journal size defined for it. If the journal size is big, less files are needed, ergo less file descriptors (and their associated resources) are needed.

There is also a nice blog post on disk space usage, here. It is a bit older, and might not be accurate now, but it should give you a general idea.

https://www.arangodb.com/2012/07/collection-disk-usage-arangodb/

Regarding journal-sizes and performance, you should also look at this:
https://www.arangodb.com/2012/09/performance-different-journal-sizes/

Comment: I can confirm that each database will add overhead in terms of its own system collections, so it will at least use disk space and some memory. Additionally, for each database there will be one or two dedicated software threads. These will be idle most of the time if there is no activity in the database, but active from time to time if there is also activity in the database.